# tensorflow documentation says "WARNING: Avoid writing code which relies on the value of a Variable..." what does it mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The [tf.Variable documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) 
contains the following warning:

> WARNING: tf.Variable objects by default have a non-intuitive memory model. A Variable is represented internally as a mutable Tensor which can non-deterministically alias other Tensors in a graph. The set of operations which consume a Variable and can lead to aliasing is undetermined and can change across TensorFlow versions. Avoid writing code which relies on the value of a Variable either changing or not changing as other operations happen. For example, using Variable objects or simple functions thereof as predicates in a tf.cond is dangerous and error-prone:

```
v = tf.Variable(True)
tf.cond(v, lambda: v.assign(False), my_false_fn)  # Note: this is broken.
```

I don't quite understand what time means and why the example above is broken. What does it mean that one cannot rely on the value of a Variable? Is it possible to have an example where the code above works not as expected?

Answer (score 0):

**As the documentation of TensorFlow you should use:**

```
v = tf.Variable(True, use_resource=True)
tf.cond(v, lambda: v.assign(False), my_false_fn)
```

**See here for more information:**

[tf.Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable)